# Umlaut in Gothic

Tags: germanic-languages, proto-germanic, gothic

It's said that Gothic had no umlaut, but there would seem to be, although I'm sure it's not, signs of a-umlaut.
The digraph au in Gothic is thought to have represented three different sounds, one of which was a short o, as in Gothic waurd or Dauhtar. I've read that Proto-Germanic did not have a short o, and that in words like gold and horn, a short u was lowered by a following a.
Would the short o in Gothic be the result of something else, and if so, what?

Answer (score 6):

It's the result of lowering of /u/ before the consonants /h~x/, /hʷ~xʷ~ʍ/ and /r/. According to Winfred P. Lehmann in *[Gothic and the Reconstruction of Proto-Germanic](https://books.google.com/books?id=w-BcAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=Gothic%20short%20o&source=bl&ots=X1GjQU_Fiy&sig=rDVq0fprkRBw7avri5wH9ak8qKQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjruPjKqafQAhXMy4MKHUq5DvgQ6AEIPTAK#v=onepage&q=Gothic%20short%20o&f=false),* short /o/ and /u/ (and short /e/ and /i/) were nearly in complementary distribution in Gothic, but further sound changes that occured after the process of lowering created some exceptions to this general pattern, such as *aíþþau* "or" and *hiri* "here".